# Dropbox .deb package fails to install on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, dropbox

I did a fresh install of Kubuntu 22.04. Tried to install dropbox by downloading the .deb package, but I'm getting the following error. I do:

```
sudo apt install ./dropbox_2022.12.05_amd64.deb
```

and it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'dropbox' instead of './dropbox_2022.12.05_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dropbox : Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't even understand the error, let alone trying to fix it. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means (oversimplified) that a December 2022 Dropbox package is not compatible with an April 2022 Kubuntu release.

Let's take a look at the Dropbox download page:

[image]

According to the filename, you downloaded the .deb that is labeled for Ubuntu 22.10 (including Kubuntu 22.10) and newer. However, you are running Kubuntu 22.04.

You downloaded the wrong .deb package for your release of Kubuntu. You should not have these problems using the appropriate deb package for your release of Kubuntu.

Comment: I updated to 23.04. I was too tired to notice 22.10 is newer than 22.04. Thank you for the explanation.